# Tuple of objects that, if referenced directly, returns first object

Tags: python, tuples

I want to modify one of the API methods which returns an object. I think it should return a tuple of objects. I don't want to change the way people call this API method. Is there any way to return a tuple of objects that can be referenced directly for the first object?

Comment: What type of object is normally returned?

Answer (score 0):

If you change a function that returned an object to instead return a tuple, then the callers of the function will have to be changed.  There is no way around that.  Either you change the callers to extract just the first object, or the unchanged code will have a tuple where it used to have an object.